# Can't find a way to make multiple lines in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm aware of the fact that pygame's `screen.blit` is not meant to support multiple lines, however I can't figure out a work around.  All of the other threads that ask this question just don't work with my code.  How do I make this work?

I've tried to split response into two by using `splitline()` on `DisplayRoom.prompt` and then having the game just load two lines separately, but `DisplayRoom.prompt.splitline()` does not turn `DisplayRoom.prompt  from a tuple to a list and only returns the value for it.

```py
screen.fill(background_colour)
txt_surface = userfont.render(text, True, color)
screen.blit(txt_surface, (100, 800))
response = promptfont.render(DisplayRoom.prompt, True, color)
screen.blit(response, (80, 300))
pygame.display.flip()
clock.tick_busy_loop(60)  # limit FPS
```

When I defined `DisplayRoom.prompt`, I expected \n to linebreak it but it doesn't work which is why I'm here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not `Surface.blit` which doesn't support multiple lines. `blit` simply draw a `Surface` on another `Surface`, it doesn't care what the `Surface` contains.

It's [pygame.Font.render](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render) which doesn't support multilines. The docs clearly say:

> The text can only be a single line: newline characters are not rendered.

So I don't know what `DisplayRoom.prompt` is in your code, but if is not a string, is bound to fail: `render` raises a `TypeError: text must be a unicode or bytes`.
And if is a string with newlines, newlines are just not rendered.

You have to split the text and render each line separately.

In the following example I create a simple function `blitlines` which illustrates how you could do.

```
import sys
import pygame

def blitlines(surf, text, renderer, color, x, y):
    h = renderer.get_height()
    lines = text.split('\n')
    for i, ll in enumerate(lines):
        txt_surface = renderer.render(ll, True, color)
        surf.blit(txt_surface, (x, y+(i*h)))


background_colour = (0, 0, 0)
textcolor = (255, 255, 255)

multitext = "Hello World!\nGoodbye World!\nI'm back World!"

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
userfont = pygame.font.Font(None, 40)

screen.fill(background_colour)
blitlines(screen, multitext, userfont, textcolor, 100, 100)

pygame.display.flip()

#main loop
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
```

This is the result on the screen.

[image: sample image]

Comment: [`pygame.Font.render`](https://pyga.me/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render) in `pygame-ce` since `2.1.4` does support newlines, more info about the fork can be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/1112q10/pygame_community_edition_announcement/)